# Skip echo test in big blue button BBB

Tags: spring-boot, api, quarkus, bigbluebutton, quarkus-rest-client

I wanted to unmute mic  or skip echo test on create or join meeting. I have tried several way and made changes in the settings.yml file and passed parameter bbb_skip_check_audio = true in create meeting url but I didn't get expected output.

Could you please suggest how can I skip complete echo test in BBB. mic should be unmute on start meeting or join meeting.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and someone will help you. with the information you provide its virtually imposible to know what can be happening.

Comment: @Pramod why did you tag the question with Quarkus and Quarkus REST Client?

Comment: @MichałSzynkiewicz I have created BBB rest api in quarkus application hence I tagged the quarkus rest clinet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are setting bbb_skip_check_audio parameter wrongly because there should not be any space between `=` sign and values. set this paramater with no spaces like this:

```
bbb_skip_check_audio=true
```

I suggest testing parameters in api-mate project in [here](https://mconf.github.io/api-mate/)